# How to configure code climate to count the lines of code in a Haskell project

Tags: haskell, code-climate

Code climate counts the lines of code in our project, but it seems to ignore Haskell files (only Java files are counted). Is there a way to configure code climate to change this behavior?

Comment: It does not seem to support Haskell: https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/supported-languages-for-maintainability

Comment: Not out of the box, but we are using it with `hlint`. Since there are off-the-shelf tools to count the lines of codes of any language (like [`sloc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc)) I was wondering if there was some tweak we could use. But indeed, the fact that Haskell is not officially supported gives me little hope :/